# fixing and understanding an error in a very simple Navision dataport

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2009

Can someone please tell me why my code would error out on CU 5402 UOM Mgmt, specifically at the Item.Testfield("No.) line under GetQtyPerUnitofMeasure function? Below is my code to import 6 columns of data: locationcode,item,variantcode,qty,UOM,BusinessEntity.

I already set up a Item Journal template called Item with batch name = AU007. I can't understand why it would error out. Please help.

I have included the data from my csv file here...

AU007   A045    001-00  1   EA  AU
AU007   A045    1882-00 1   EA  AU
AU007   A045    1887-00 -1  EA  AU
AU007   A045    511-00  1   EA  AU

The error is You must specify No. in ItemNo?

```
>Integer - OnBeforeImportRecord()
>LocationCode := '';
>ItemNo := '';
>VariantCode := '';
>Qty := '';
>UOM := '';
>BusinessEntity := '';
Integer - OnAfterImportRecord()
LineNo += 10000;

WITH ItemJnlLine DO BEGIN
INIT;
"Journal Template Name" := 'ITEM';
"Journal Batch Name" := 'AU007';
"Line No." := LineNo;
"Reason Code" := 'COUNT';
INSERT(TRUE);

"Posting Date" := 020117D;
VALIDATE("Entry Type",ItemJnlLine."Entry Type"::"Positive Adjmt.");
"Document No." := 'AU_invcount';
IF EVALUATE("Location Code",LocationCode) THEN
VALIDATE("Location Code");
IF EVALUATE("Item No.",ItemNo) THEN
VALIDATE("Item No.");
IF EVALUATE("Variant Code",VariantCode) THEN
VALIDATE("Variant Code");
IF EVALUATE(Quantity,Qty) THEN
VALIDATE(Quantity);
IF EVALUATE("Unit of Measure Code",UOM) THEN
VALIDATE("Unit of Measure Code");
IF EVALUATE("Shortcut Dimension 2 Code",BusinessEntity) THEN
VALIDATE("Shortcut Dimension 2 Code");
MODIFY(TRUE);
END;
```

Comment: Maybe you have an empty last line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I estimate that the error is in some validate function, in these lines you check if can EVALUETE "Item No." field an then you assing the value else "Item No." It has no value.

```
IF EVALUATE("Item No.",ItemNo) THEN
    VALIDATE("Item No.");
```

So, in the others validates "Item No." field is "".

Try this:

```
IF EVALUATE("Item No.",ItemNo) THEN BEGIN
    LineNo += 10000;

    WITH ItemJnlLine DO BEGIN
        INIT;
        "Journal Template Name" := 'ITEM';
        "Journal Batch Name" := 'AU007';
        "Line No." := LineNo;
        "Reason Code" := 'COUNT';
        INSERT(TRUE);

        "Posting Date" := 020117D;
        VALIDATE("Entry Type",ItemJnlLine."Entry Type"::"Positive Adjmt.");
        "Document No." := 'AU_invcount';
        IF EVALUATE("Location Code",LocationCode) THEN
            VALIDATE("Location Code");
        IF EVALUATE("Item No.",ItemNo) THEN
            VALIDATE("Item No.");
        IF EVALUATE("Variant Code",VariantCode) THEN
            VALIDATE("Variant Code");
        IF EVALUATE(Quantity,Qty) THEN
            VALIDATE(Quantity);
        IF EVALUATE("Unit of Measure Code",UOM) THEN
            VALIDATE("Unit of Measure Code");
        IF EVALUATE("Shortcut Dimension 2 Code",BusinessEntity) THEN
            VALIDATE("Shortcut Dimension 2 Code");
        MODIFY(TRUE);
    END;
END;
```